# SMALI HELP - GET String from resource

Tags: android, string, resources, smali

I decompiled an apk with APKTool and in one .smali file I got this code:

```
.class public Lc/c/a/a;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "SourceFile"

# instance fields
.field public a:Ljava/lang/String;

# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 1

    .line 1
    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    const-string v0, "Choose Storage"

    .line 2
    iput-object v0, p0, Lc/c/a/a;->a:Ljava/lang/String;

    return-void
.end method
```

My problem was that the "const-string, v0" i need to get it from the resourse file.
I try to add into the fields, incremented the locals

```
.field public l:Landroid/content/Context;
```

and then added the next code after the "const-string v0":

```
const v1, 0x7f1200a3

iget-object v0, p0, Lc/c/a/a;->l:Landroid/content/Context;

invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0
```

But the app crash when open in this point.

FULL MODIFIED CODE

```
.class public Lc/c/a/a;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "SourceFile"

# instance fields
.field public a:Ljava/lang/String;

.field public l:Landroid/content/Context;

# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 2

    .line 1
    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    const-string v0, "Choose Storage"

    const v1, 0x7f1200a3

    iget-object v0, p0, Lc/c/a/a;->l:Landroid/content/Context;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 2
    iput-object v0, p0, Lc/c/a/a;->a:Ljava/lang/String;

    return-void
.end method
```

ERROR FROM LOGCAT

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String andoid.content.Contect.getString(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: If the app crashes, the first thing you should look at (and include when asking for help) is the errors for the crash in logcat :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `l` is no value, try construct with a Context.

```
.class public Lc/c/a/a;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "SourceFile"

# instance fields
.field public a:Ljava/lang/String;

.field public l:Landroid/content/Context;

# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V
    .locals 3

    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V
    
    #Assign value to l
    iput-object p1, p0, Lc/c/a/a;->l:Landroid/content/Context;
    
    const v0, 0x7f1200a3

    invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Landroid/content/Context;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    iput-object v0, p0, Lc/c/a/a;->a:Ljava/lang/String;

    return-void
.end method
```

just like this
[image: compiled]